# Run Command from Directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, tensorflow

I've been programming an AI for a while now, and I need the capacity to interact with Google's TensorFlow Object Detection API locally. I downloaded TensorFlow through Anaconda, and I'm having trouble with this step:

```
# From tensorflow/models/research/

protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

I'm on Windows, and I'm not sure how to run this from that directory using Anaconda. I cannot use Command Prompt for this task.

Comment: # From tensorflow/models/research/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim              Same question for this

Comment: Suppose you have the `tensorflow` environment in your Anaconda. Then you can run `protoc` after running the command `activate tensorflow` in your command prompt (`cmd`).